# How to make a proper Regex

Tags: regex

I have what I think is a fairly simple question on making a Regex.  Here's my string:

```
  Confl 2284341         /FOLDER﻿﻿/PATH/file.xlsx
```

I want to make sure the line has "Confl" in it, and I want to capture the full path.  What I came up with is:

```
.*Confl .*(\/.+)
```

But this only captures the file name, not the full path (I can live with not getting the initial forward slash).  Seemed like it would be straight forward, but it *is* Regex, so...

Anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
.*Confl .*(\/.+)
```

To

```
.*Confl .*?(/.+)
```

This will prevent the middle `.*` from being "[greedy](https://www.google.com/search?q=greedy%20possessive%20reluctant%20quantifiers)" and capturing everything up to the *last* slash. Instead, the question-mark makes it "possessive", so it stops before the *first* slash, which is your goal.

Unless there is something I'm misunderstanding, you also don't need the escape slash before the up-right slash, which I've removed.

Comment: Had to keep the escape than forward slash \/ otherwise it didn't capture the path name.  But the question mark was the key!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
\bConfl [^\/]*(\/\S*)
```

`\b` is a word boundary

`[^\/]` means "all characters that are not a slash"

`\S` is a non white characters